# How to add the list<string> returned fom a method to an array of type string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i'm dynamically binding an html select control with a list. The problem is , it's not possible to declare a list in an aspx page. How can i bind each element from the list returned to the select control? The code is shown below :

```
 <select title="select table" id="ddlTableNames" onchange="getTableName()" onload="SetTableNameToParameter()">
            <!-- onload="fromHtmlDropDown()" -->
            <option>Select</option>
            <%

              for (int i = 0; i < metaData.GetTables().Count; i++)
              {
            %>
            <option>
              <%=metaData.GetTables()[i]%></option> // I need to store the return value to something. Dont know the array syntax for this on an aspx page
            <% 
              } 
            %>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for here, but assuming the values contained in that returned list/array make sense to display as strings (which it looks like they do from your example), then the following might be a simpler approach :

```
<select title="select table" id="ddlTableNames" onchange="getTableName()" onload="SetTableNameToParameter()">
<option>Select</option>
<% foreach (var table in metaData.GetTables()) { %>
    <option><%= table %></option>
<% } %>
```

Is this solving your problem?  If not, help me understand exactly what you're trying to solve.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Infact, I need to avoid calling that method multiple times. Here also to get the value in table, the method will be executing multiple times,right?

Comment: No. Only one call to GetTables().  The returned list is then iterated over.